# no puedo obtener datos de la base de datos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo un error que me esta ocurriendo desde hace dos días el cual no entiendo que pueda ser, es cuando intento obtener la información de la base de datos con el modelo de empleados, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from apps.empleado.forms import EmpleadoForm
from apps.empleado.models import Empleado

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'empleado/index.html')

def empleado_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmpleadoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/empleado')
    else:
        form = EmpleadoForm()

    return render(request, 'empleado/alta.html', {'form':form})

def empleado_list(request):
    empleado = Empleado.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'empleado/index.html', {'empleados':empleado})

class EmpleadoList(ListView):
    model = Empleado
    template_name='empleado/index.html'
```

y en error que me aparece es el siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podria ayudarme que podria ser este error?, intenet usando algo llamado django-lint pero parece ser que lo configure mal o sera que esa no es la solucion, estoy usando Django 2.0.2 con las siguientes librerias instaladas via pip:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.2
attrs==17.4.0
Automat==0.6.0
cffi==1.11.5
colorama==0.3.9
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.4
cssselect==1.0.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.2
django-filter==1.1.0
django-material==1.2.2
django-materialize-css==0.0.1
django-report-builder==4.0.3
django-reset-migrations==0.3.1
django-viewflow==1.2.2
djangorestframework==3.7.7
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.6
incremental==17.5.0
isort==4.3.4
jdcal==1.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lxml==4.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mysqlclient==1.3.12
numpy==1.14.1
openpyxl==2.5.0
parsel==1.4.0
Pillow==5.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycparser==2.18
pylint==1.8.3
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2018.3
reportlab==3.4.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
w3lib==1.19.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
wrapt==1.10.11
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

no las estoy usando todas pero quise ponerlas completas por si dejaba pasar alguna, gracias por su ayuda espero puedan ayudarme

PD: en el shell de Django funciona bien los metodos para guardar, consultar, modificar y eliminar los datos, solamente no funciona para obtenerlos cuando los estoy usando en la vista

Edit1: este es el codigo del modelo empleado

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator 

#from apps.estado.models import Estado
#from apps.sucursal.models import Sucursal
#from apps.kernel.models import Estatus #Error de compilador por alguna razon

# Create your models here.
class Genero(models.Model):
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.genero)

class TipoEmpleado(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)

class Empleado(models.Model):
    #emplado_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    no_reloj = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40) #40
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=25) #25
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True) #25
    genero = models.ForeignKey('empleado.Genero', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, null=True, unique=True) #120
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18, null=True, unique=True) #18
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, unique=True) #13
    nss = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True) #11
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True) #120
    sucursal = models.ForeignKey('sucursal.Sucursal', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.ForeignKey('estado.Estado', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #6
    fecha_alta = models.DateField(null=True)
    estatus = models.ForeignKey('kernel.Estatus', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_nac = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s) %s %s' % (self.no_reloj, self.nombre, self.apellido_paterno)
```

Este es el codigo de la pagina index.html:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block titleApp %}
    Empleados
{% endblock titleApp %}


{% block content %}
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col">

        <!-- Iniciamos una lista de los empleados a mostrar -->
        <ul class="demo-list-two mdl-list">

            {% if empleados %}
            {% for empleado in empleados %}

                <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line">
                    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                        <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
                        <span>({{ empleado.no_reloj }}) {{ empleado.nombre }}</span>
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-sub-title">
                            <a id="email_info" class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">email</i>bryan.cranston@oasis.com</a> <a id="phone_info" class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">call</i>(656)123-1234</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-info">Editar</span>
                        <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i id="edit_person" class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <h1>No hay empleados registrados.</h1>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <!-- Termina la lista de empleados de la BD -->
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--left" data-mdl-for="edit_person">
            Editar informacion <br/> de este empleado.
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--right" data-mdl-for="input_field">
            Agrega un texto.
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--right" data-mdl-for="email_info">
            Correo de contacto.
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--right" data-mdl-for="phone_info">
            Telefono de contacto.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Edit2: agregue el codivo completo de view.py

Comment: Pon el código del modelo Empleado

Comment: listo, acabo de agregar el codigo del modelo

Comment: aparentemente todo esta bien, la función empleado_view te funciona? lo que puede estar pasando es que estas inicializando la variable Emplado en alguna parte de tu codigo

Comment: acabo de agregar el codigo completo de view.py la funcion empleado_view no me retorna nada en mi html cuando quiero mostrar los datos en una lista con Material Design Lite

Comment: Yo digo que más bien es problema de tu entorno de desarrollo y la configuración con el visual code estudio, revisa bien la configuración del linter, que lo tengas bien instalado y que sobretodo, trabaje con el path del entorno virtual en el que corres la app. Ya que si la app corre sin ningún problema, entonces el problema es el linter

Comment: como puedo configurar ambas cosas?, o comprobar que ambas cosas estén trabajando correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

prueba poniendo el import dentro de la función por si estas cambiando el valor por alaguna parte

```
def empleado_list(request):
    from apps.empleado.models import Empleado
    empleado = Empleado.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'empleado/index.html', {'empleados':empleado})
```

lo otro un import se suele hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
from empleado.models import Empledo
```

prueba haciendo asi el import, si esto funciona puede que tengas mal estructurado tu proyecto

Lo otro, asegurate de haber añadido tus apps a INSTALLED_APPS  en setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'empleado', # aunque en tu caso podria ser 'apps.empleado'
]
```

Comment: lo tengo como apps.empleado.models por que todas las apps estan dentro de un folder con ese nombre, aun asi podria usarlo como lo tienes de from empleado.models import Empleado ?

Comment: lo más comun es crear un directorio proyecto por ejemplo "tienda" y dentro de esta crear las apps "empleados" , "productos", etc comprueba si tu funciona poneindolo asi .sino ponme un pantallazo de como tiens los directorios, y una recomendacion no pongas mas codigo en el caso del modelo con Empleado me valia por tu error no hace falta q pongas el html

Comment: te he modificado mi respuesta, hechale un vistazo

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'material',
    'material.frontend',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'reset_migrations',
    'apps.captura',
    'apps.cliente',
    'apps.cotizacion',
    'apps.empleado',
    'apps.reportes',
    'apps.sucursal',
    'apps.estado',
    'apps.pais',
    'apps.utils',
    'apps.usuario',
    'apps.kernel',
]`

asi es como esta mi INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: y asi es como tengo el diretorio de archivos

https://i.imgur.com/K2eZvFG.png

Comment: alguien copio el trabajo que estaba haciendo??

Answer (score -1):

Trata de hacerlo de la siguiente manera solo para verificar si te entrega datos antes de entrar en el for solo imprime el valor de la lista query

{{% empleados %}}

Comment: esto es más un comentario, cuando tengas mayor reputación podrás comentar.